# Two Gateways on a single network - VPN into 1 gateway, but limited access

Tags: routing, vpn

I have two gateway routers as I have two different internet providers, I have one for high speed/normal use (Gateway 1), and the other slower speed, but dedicated IP's (Gateway 2).  It is all working great.

I have VPN setup on Router (Gateway) 2 with my phone.  The problem is I can only access devices attached to Gateway 2, not Gateway 1.  I need to also access Gateway 1.  Everything is the same subnet, so I really can't have two VPN's at the same time right?  Is there a special routing that can be set up so that I can access Gateway 1's devices?

I have RV325's for the routers.

Comment: You need to share routes between your routers. You can do this with a routing protocol, or you can configure static routes (doesn't scale and isn't dynamic, but may work for a small network) in your routers.

Comment: Even though it is the same subnet?

Comment: Yes. How does Gateway 1 know about the network for the VPN? Routers learn routes in three ways: directly connected networks, statically configured routes, or routes dynamically learned through a routing protocol. Gateway 1 has no inherent knowledge of any routes on Gateway 2 to which it is not directly connected (and vice versa), and it needs to be told about the other routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the devices using Gateway1 as default gateway, you need to add a static route with the VPN pool subnet pointing to Gateway2. Alternatively, you can add that route to Gateway1. (Or better yet - as Ron suggested - set up dynamic routing.)

As it is, they're using the default gateway which is (apparently) routing the packets out to the Internet. Instead the packets need to go back into the tunnel.

Comment: You and Ron Maupin are both correct, the issue was I needed a route set up in my Router (my 10.10.1.1 router) to the IP range that the second router's VPN server was giving my Phone's VPN Client.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the static route from gateway 1 network to gateway 2 networks

==>> As destination as supernet for lan pool  pointing towards gateways 2 networks interface .

==>> And make sure  route entry for reverse traffic from gateway 2 to gateway 1

==>> As destination as "VPN pool subnet " pointing towards gateway 1 interface .